# Jerky moving image or text on DirectX or Opengl

Tags: directx, marquee

Background is i'm developing a component which is like a digital signage, with moving ticker text runs from left to right in loop, lays over a playing video or still image.

But the ticker text is not fluid enough, especially when a video is loaded from inside or outside the application, it jerks very much.

I have been stuck by this issue for years, technologies I have tested include D3D and WPF.

I never tried OpenGL, however persoannly i think it equals to D3D.

Can you give me some guidelines or even samples?

Comment: Hello and again welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question contains a great lack of information. It is unclear exactly what the problem is, what particular code you're using, your timing mechanisms, or anything that might shed light on the situation.

Comment: To put it simple, my intention is to create a moving text/image across the screen which is required to be very smooth, any lagging effect is unacceptable. It's nothing with any particular code. (unclear if the complementary information is enough or not)

Comment: You cannot make a [pre-emptive multitasking OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29#Preemptive_multitasking) (pretty much any system you're running on outside of real-time systems) give you however much CPU time you want. If the user is doing something in the background that draws more CPU than you need, your application will slow down. And quite frankly, your application's marquee text is not important enough to the user to warrant such consideration from the OS. In short: *deal with it*.